# Show that the support restriction is not stringent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the family of continuous distribution functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Fix a vector of reals $\theta\equiv (t, u)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Fix a vector of  positive reals $p\equiv (p_1,p_2,p_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3_{+}$ such that $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

**Assumption 1:** There exists $P\in \mathcal{P}$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& p_1=P(x\geq -t, z\geq u-t)\\
& p_2=P(y\geq -u,z<u-t))\\
& p_3=P(x<-t, y<-u)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

**Clarification about the notation**: $P(x\geq -t, z\geq u-t)$ denotes the probability measure of the box $[-t,\infty)\times (-\infty,\infty)\times [u-t,\infty)$. That is,
$$
P(x\geq -t, z\geq u-t)\equiv P(\{(x,y,z): (x,y,z)\in [-t,\infty)\times (-\infty,\infty)\times [u-t,\infty)\})
$$

**Note:** I'm not restricting the support of $P$. However, note that $P$ cannot have full support on $\mathbb{R}^3$ under Assumption 1. For instance, Assumption 1 implies that
$$
P(x\geq -t, y<-u, z<u-t)=0\\
P(x<-t, y\geq -u, z\geq u-t)=0
$$

---

**Question:** I would like your help to show **Claim 1**:

**Claim 1**: If Assumption 1 holds, then there exists a distribution $H\in \mathcal{P}$ whose support is
$$
\mathcal{B}\equiv \{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3: a=b+c\}
$$
and satisfying all the conditions of Assumption 1.

---

**This may be helpful 1:** Take a distribution $H$ whose support is
$$
\mathcal{B}\equiv \{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3: a=b+c\}
$$

I believe that this is equivalent to impose
$$
H(x\geq a+b, y< a, z< b)=0\\
H(x< a+b, y\geq  a, z\geq  b)=0
$$
for each $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

---

**This may be helpful 2:** Assumption 1 comes from  from discrete choice modelling in econometrics. Suppose there are 3 alternatives among which one has to choose. Suppose that each alternative $j$ gives you utility $\eta_j+v_j$, where $\eta_j$ is a random variable and $v_j$ is a number. You will choose option 1 with probability $\Pr(\eta_1+v_1\geq \eta_2+v_2, \eta_1+v_1\geq \eta_3+v_3)$. Write this also for $j= 2,3$ and redefine the differences of $\eta$'s and $v$'s. Assume $v_3=0$. You will obtain Assumption 1. You can switch minuses and pluses as you like if you find it more intuitive.

---

**This may be helpful 3:** I've done several simulations which  confirm Claim 1. Clearly, such simulations are not a formal proof. In case you have a counterexample of Claim 1 in mind, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0< 2u-t$. Let $X$ be a real continuous random variable such that $$P(X> \max\{-t/2,u-t\})=p_1, \quad P(X \in [-u,u-t])=p_2, \quad P(X< \min\{-t/2,-u\})=p_3.$$

Then the distribution of the vector $(2X,X,X)$ is a solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I fully get the connection with my question. I have 3D vectors.

Comment: $(2X,X,X)$ is a random vector, its distribution is supported on the set you wanted and it satisfies your conditions in assumption 1.